# popup on exit page but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple page that displays a exitpop whenever the user click the exit the page button which is the x button at the top right of the tab.

it is defined under

```
`
    var popit = true;
    window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
     if(popit == true) {
       popit = false;
       return "Warte ab!! Es gibt noch (2) Preise! Verpassen Sie sie nicht!"; 
 }
}`
```

my problem is i have a meta-refresh
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://vtk.wasrcs.com/click">`

as a result every 5 seconds it will refresh. then the exitpop displays..

I don't want the exitpop to be displayed everytime the page refreshed or click the back button.

what i need is to make the exit pop should only display in the exit button not on page refresh nor back button.

i need help on this guys,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the meta refresh to achieve that as you don't know if the meta refresh or the user triggers the `onbeforeunload` event.

Handle the page refresh with `setTimeout(function() {popit = false; window.location.href ='http://vtk.wasrcs.com/click'}, 5000)`

Setting `popit` to `false` just before the refresh will prevent the message to appear as you test `if(popit == true)`.

Although, all that doesn't look very user friendly...